# What is the the total number of “magic” circles for a given N?

Tags: combinatorics

I came across this this question helping my son with similar math. tasks.

Consider the circle with $2^n$ items on its periphery. Each item holds 0 or 1. For each item consider sequence of n items to the right.

We get the set of $2^n$ sequences of 0 or 1, each of length = n.

Are there “magic” circles for which the set consists of all possible n-length combinations of 1 and 0?
The answer is yes, I found examples for n = 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Please visit https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx5nWEBuM6XKYW9taWg4QWpLTFU to see examples.

If the condition holds for a circle, it also holds

- if we get sequences to the left from each item
- if we replace 0 with 1, and 1 with 0 for each item (example: 3A --> 3B)
- if we take the specular reflection of the circle (example: 4A --> 4C)

QUESTION: what is the number of such "magic" circles for a given n?

Answer (score 0):

This is the sequence [OEIS A016031](http://oeis.org/A016031) in the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/); the entry gives the answer as $2^{2^{n-1}-n}$, with references. It grows very rapidly: for $n=0,1,2,3,4,5$, and $6$ the values are $1,1,2,16,2048,67108864$, and $144115188075855872$.

Comment: @Andrey: You’re welcome.